# Load different JS using JSP according to Internet Explorer version

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I'm kinda new to JSP and right now I'm stumped on a problem that most of us wouldn't wish to encounter: Internet Explorer 6.0 support.

I've scoured over Google and found no answer. My question is, is there a way to load a different Javascript inside a JSP according to the browser version?

My algorithm would be:
Check Internet Explorer version.
IF IE6, load ie6.js
ELSE load normal.js.

So far, this is how I load my JS.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/normal.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [conditinal comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_Comments) to load different Javascript for Internet Explorer.

So, for your case:

```
<!--[if !IE 6]><!-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="normal.js" />
<!--<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ie6.js" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `navigator` object like this:

```
     var ua = navigator.userAgent;
     if(navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'){
            //check for version

            var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
            if (re.exec(ua) != null){
              version = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
            }
            if(version == 6.0){
               //load specific js for IE 6.0
               var file = document.createElement("script");
               file.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
               file.setAttribute("src", "../js/ie_6.js");
               document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(file);
            }
            else{
                //load normal.js for other IE versions.
                var file = document.createElement("script");
                file.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
                file.setAttribute("src", "../js/normal.js");
                document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(file);
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this on the server side, you would have to check `User-Agent` HTTP header. After this you could set some attribute to current request and later check that attribute in JSP page:

```
...
String browserString = httpServletRequest.getHeader("User-Agent");

String browserVersion = ...; // Some user agent parsing and version determining

httpServletRequest.setAttribute("browserVersion", browserVersion);
```

User agent examples can be found on internet, e.g. http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Internet%20Explorer/.